# utilizing grep regex expressions with multiple conditions

Tags: regex, unix

So I am trying to come up with a code that examines

1. if a string has duplicate character at the beginning of the sentence, and

aa....., bb.....

2. if the string ends with duplicate character.

....aa, .....bb

I am trying to combine the two conditions and see if any of the strings in my text file match the conditions.

so far, I have learned about using egrep

and with it I could do first part of the algorithm

```
egrep '^(.)\1{1}' *.txt
```

but when I try to combine it with the second part,

```
egrep '^(.)\1{1}|(.)\1{1}$' *.txt
```

the second part is ignored and the result is the same as before.

What can I do to combine multiple patterns into the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the alternation you have to refer to group 2 in the second part as you have 2 capturing groups.

Note that you can omit the `{1}` quantifier.

```
^(.)\1|(.)\2$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJ83cg/1)

Your code could look like:

```
egrep '^(.)\1|(.)\2$' *.txt
```

To match both a duplicate char at the start and at the end you could use:

```
^(.)\1.*(.)\2$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZ9Coa/1/)

Comment: Would there be a way to output only the strings that satisfy both the conditions 1 and 2? egrep '^(.)\1|(.)\2$' *.txt would output results that satisfy either condition 1 or 2.

Comment: @VAnon In that case you could use `^(.)\1.*(.)\2$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZ9Coa/1/)